# about the translation of this sentence

Tags: translation

**

> 単語検索で聴取できる男声サンプルは，ます形など，共通語では無声化されるところを無声化せずに読んでいます。また，男女ともに，名詞の音声サンプルは提供していません。

**

My translation is :As for the the male sample that could be heard by the word search, masu form and common terms..... it will be voicelessly changed when reading voiclessly ??? also , we can not offer voive samples that are both female and male  .

And what does

> ところを

mean in this context ?

Comment: Please use a reliable dictionary for unfamiliar terms. 無声化 is generally translated as 'devoiced' or 'unvoiced'.